# How can I generate public address from an xpub key in Java?

Tags: bitcoin-core, public-key, bitcoinj, java, xpub

I have an xpub key with which I want to generate all addresses which have been used or will be used and then find out the keys which have balance.

Here's a sample xpubkey with balance- xpub6CUGRUonZSQ4TWtTMmzXdrXDtypWKiKrhko4egpiMZbpiaQL2jkwSB1icqYh2cfDfVxdx4df189oLKnC5fSwqPfgyP3hooxujYzAu3fDVmz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generate wallet addresses from extended public key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73013/generate-wallet-addresses-from-extended-public-key)

Comment: Hi Ugam, I tried the method but it doesn't work for me. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows low to no investigation effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have to deserialize xpub key then use its derivation path to get a child path or normal key. From a normal key, it is easy to convert the public key to address.
You can refer to this source code.
https://github.com/tatumio/tatum-java/blob/master/src/main/java/io/tatum/wallet/Address.java#L24

Thanks

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer.